# EJS with rails 4 not working

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ejs

A friend and I are creating a simple web app. I am working on a side panel that will be updated depending on the params sent to a render function in the js.

I have included the ejs gem
and have a templates directory within the javascripts directory.

I have done a simple test to see if ejs is working and it looks like the following.

```
$(function() {
   $('.sidepanel').html(JST['templates/sidepanel/tools']);
});
```

When this is run, literally nothing happens...

If I attempt to pass data along to the JST I get the following error:
Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'templates/sidepanel/tools'

For the life of me I can't seam to figure out what is going on. I have tried google for the past 3 hours, and have found no help.

Is there something I am missing? I have tried this in a rails 3.2 project and everything worked accordingly.

Thanks for any help!

-Mike

Comment: lets tart debugging!  Please post your `templates/sidepanel/tools` file if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to anybody who has looked at this.
There was a slight error in the naming that I had used in my project. Simply put - a spelling mistake. I had been working all day and night, and I guess my eyes could no longer pick out mistakes like this. After taking an hour break. The error jumped right out at me.

Thanks a lot.